# How can i assign result URI from image Capture to ImageView or ImageButton?

Tags: android

I have  Imagebutton  or  image  view in Main.xml

How can i assign result URI to ImageView or ImageButton?

```
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

  if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK && requestCode == 0) {
    String result = data.toURI();
}

}


public void onClick(DialogInterface arg0, int arg1) {

                Intent intent = new Intent("android.media.action.IMAGE_CAPTURE");
                startActivityForResult(intent, 0);


            }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's simple

```
mPhotoView.setImageURI(uri);
```